# How can I "broadcast" negative sampling using NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently trying to perform negative sampling where I have an array of integers and a certain number of positive sample integers contained within this range. My current algorithm is as follows:

```
total = 50000
positive_samples = np.random.choice(np.arange(total), size=(30000,), replace=False)

def get_negative_samples(positive_samples, num_negatives=100):
    negative_samples = []
    for positive_sample in positive_samples:
        candidates = np.concatenate((np.arange(positive_sample), np.arange(positive_sample + 1, total)))
        sampled = np.random.choice(candidates, size=(num_negatives,), replace=False)
        negative_samples.append(sampled)

    return negative_samples
```

This code is slow because it uses a for loop and creates rather large candidate lists. I'm wondering if it would be possible to achieve something where I have the list of positive samples and I would be able to efficiently get the negative sample candidates *and* perform negative sampling.

Comment: ```NameError: name 'total' is not defined``` also can you provide an example with input and desired output

Comment: @Sure I'll edit it into the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can randomly choose from the *total* range, and to avoid the *positive_samples* you just have to set their probabilities to 0.
The sum of `probs` has to be `1` , thats why its divided with the num of not positive samples.

```
probs=np.ones(total)/(total-len(positive_samples))
probs[positive_samples]=0
sampled = np.random.choice(np.arange(total),size=(num_negatives),p=probs, replace=False)
```

Comment: Doesn't this return a single array of shape `(nun_negatives,)`? I really like your approach of zeroing out the probabilities, but I'd like a way to get a distinct negative sample array for _each_ positive sample.

Comment: Ohh you are right, I was unsure about whether thats intentional.